# Why would 'Open connection failed:sql: unknown driver "mssql" (forgotten import?)' happen the first time on a go build?

Tags: go

The first time I ran https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/blob/master/examples/simple.go I got the error 'Open connection failed:sql: unknown driver "mssql" (forgotten import?)'

I resolved this by changing 
    import _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
to
    import "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"

Which gave a different error of 'imported and not used: "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb" as mssql'.

However ... after changing back to  import _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb" and building again the first error went away.

I also had to change the main function name from 'simplemain' to 'main' for some reason before it would compile.

Why would the error 'Open connection failed:sql: unknown driver "mssql" (forgotten import?)' happen on the first build?

Answer (score 3):

Intended way of use seems to be

```
import _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
```

which purpose is to run package's init() functions

```
func init() {
sql.Register("mssql", &MssqlDriver{})
}
```

most likely it's a some typo cause the error.

Comment: There was no typo. I literally removed the underscore. Compiled. Ran. Different error. Put the underscore back in. No error.